# If one doesnt have a kippah should he make a bracha?

Tags: blessing, kippa-yarmulka, shaat-hadechak

If one doesn't have a kippah (or anything to cover his head) should he eat without making a bracha or not make one at all?

Comment: If he's that naked then he has other problems

Comment: There is a third possibility: wait to eat until one finds a kippa, napkin, other head covering, his sleeve or a friend's hand

Comment: related: [What to do if you need to say a bracha but do not have access to a head covering?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61132/11501)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes he should make a bracha, but he should cover his head with his hand. [If he has any random material e.g. sleeve, that would be better.]

1 - There are opinions that say that one's own hand would be a good covering, and the Mishna Berura (2:12) writes that in case of need some rely on this opinion. Even though it would be better to cover the head with a sleeve or other material.

2 - The Pri Megadim (פתיחה להלכות ברכות ס"ק ו) writes that בדיעבד - after the fact, a bracha made without a covering is valid. We also know the rule that שעת הדחק כבדיעבד דמי, the time of pressure is equivilent to after the fact (ט"ז יו"ד סי' צ"א ס"ק ג). Where no head covering is available, even a random material, it would be like בדיעבד and one can make the bracha even if the hand is not considered a valid choice.

Comment: I read one's own hand doesn't count so it is better to ask someone else to cover one's head. And in a case like this, if there is no friend, to make the bracha silently as many forbid saying God's name aloud without a head covering

Comment: @mbloch - The the Mishna Berura (2:12) clearly disagrees with you.

Comment: @DannySchoemann yes I saw this. It is a machloket. Shulchan Aruch Harav prefers someone else's hand or his sleeve, but accepts one's own hand if no other possibility.